# Yii2 REST Simplify BasicAuth

Tags: php, api, rest, yii, yii2

I'm impressed with how simple it was to create a REST api in Yii2.  However, i'm having a little trouble understanding the Basic Authentication.  My needs are utterly simple and i'd like my solution to follow suit.

I need Basic token authentication here.  I'm not even against hardcoding it for now, but here's what i've done thus far.

I have database table to hold my singular token  ApiAccess(id, access_token)

**ApiAccess.php - Model** - NOTE: IDE shows syntax error on this first line

```
 class ApiAccess extends base\ApiAccessBase implements IdentityInterface
 {
   public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
   {
     return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
   }
 }
```

**Module.php** - in init() function

```
 \Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
```

I made an ApiController that each subsequent noun extends

**ApiController.php**

```
 use yii\rest\ActiveController;
 use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;
 use app\models\db\ApiAccess;

 class ApiController extends ActiveController
 {
   public function behaviors()
   {
      $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
      $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
      ];
     return $behaviors;
   }
 }
```

As it stands, accessing an api endpoint in the browser prompts for a username and password.  Request via REST Client displays access error.

**How do I properly tie HttpBasicAuth to my ApiAccess model?**

OR

**How do I hardcode an api access token?**  (First option is obviously best)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's watch and try to understand "yii" way basic auth for REST.

1st. When you adding behavior to your REST controller, you enabling basic auth:

```
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
    'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
  ];
```

As you did. What does it mean? It means that your application will parse your authorization header. It looks like:

```
Authorization : Basic base64(user:password)
```

Here is a trick for yii2. If you look at code more carefully, you will see that yii uses `access_token` from user field, so your header should look like:

```
Authorization : Basic base64(access_token:)
```

You can parse this header by your own, if you want to change this behavior:

```
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            'auth' => [$this, 'auth']
        ];
....
public function auth($username, $password)
    {
        return \app\models\User::findOne(['login' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
    }
```

2nd thing to do. You must implement `findIdentityByAccessToken()` function from identityInterface.
Why your IDE complaining?

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
```

Here's how your user class declaration should look.

From your implementation and structure:

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
   {
     return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
   }
```

you not returning object of class which implements identity interface.

How to make it properly?
Add column access_token to your users table, and return back your user model (you can look how it must look here - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/models/User.php)
If you do this - default code will work with your `findIdentityByAccessToken()` implementation.

If you don't want to add field to users table - make new one with `user_id,access_token` fields. Then your implementation should look like:

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
   {
     $apiUser = ApiAccess::find()
        ->where(['access_token' => $token])
        ->one();
     return static::findOne(['id' => $apiUser->user_id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
   }
```

Hope i could cover all of your questions.

Comment: I have this working,  and see how it's supposed to work now.  Thank you.  I still have an issue related to overriding the LDAP authentication already in place for only this module.  I will post a separate question if I cannot solve it on my own.

Comment: The findOne does not encrypt the password to see if it matches password_hash - how do I incorporate validatePassword with findOne?

Comment: @Cymbals http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-passwords.html