# Yii 2.0 API basic auth

Tags: php, api, yii, restful-authentication

I am creating a yii 2.0 rest api based on [RESTful](http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/) API .I want to apply HTTP Basic Auth or Query parameter Auth in API but could not succeed.

I implemented [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-authentication.html) for http basic auth and added

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    \Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
}
```

in  module's init() method but coulld not find where and how to setup
 authenticator behavior as follows

```
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;

public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

and what is the use of

```
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
    }
}
```

Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567658/yii2-rest-simplify-basicauth/29581963?noredirect=1#comment47361166_29581963

Comment: Look at that question