# yii2: Authentification in rest api (yii\rest\Controller)

Tags: php, rest, authentication, yii2

For my rest api I use `yii\rest\Controller`

```
class TweetController extends Controller
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            'auth' => [$this, 'auth']
        ];
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'formats' => [
                'application\json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ]
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }

    // not solved yet
    public function auth($pass)
    {}

    /**
     * @param int $count
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws \yii\base\InvalidConfigException
     */
    public function actionLastTweets($count = 10)
    {
        /**
         * @var TweetLastfinder $tweetLastFinder
         */
        $tweetLastFinder = Yii::$app->get('tweetlastfinder');

        return $tweetLastFinder->findLastTweets($count);
    }
```

also i use prettyUrls `'GET tweet/last-tweets/<count>' => 'tweet/last-tweets'`

actionLastTweets return array which one convert into json.

Idea is made simply authentication. In docs is example how to  implements IdentityInterface in model. But i don`t work with AR directly. As i understand. I need to properly write  auth() method.

I dont get it, whith value should be returned from auth() when authentification is passed? And how it will be send by request? (i mean `http://localhost/index.php/tweet/last-tweets/50` without authentication, how it change?)

For simplicity there is a string value $password = 'qwerty' and i want to check if parameter $pass equal $password - authentication passed

some kinda:

```
public function auth($pass)
{
   $password = 'qwerty';
   if ($pass == $password) { 
        authentication passed
   } else { 
        authentication failed 
   }
}
```

Comment: that is not secure by doing that you are throwing away all yii's built-in security system. HttpBasicAuth is about tokens.and there is an already implemented method `findIdentityByAccessToken` in the user class that your app is using that does that verification. check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567658/yii2-rest-simplify-basicauth).

Comment: Thanks.  But i still dont get it how, username and password will be transferred in url?

Comment: the idea is to not send them. only once then generate a token that replaces them. truth is I don't know how HttpBasicAuth works as i never implemented it before but I know it is not safe enough and should be used only if API consumer is a program running on a server.as mentioned in [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-authentication.html). check [this](http://blog.neattutorials.com/angularjs-and-yii2-part-2-authentication/) about Bearer Token (oauth2) it has a nice image that shows the cycle when using token instead of username/pass

Answer (score 0):

The subject of the authentication is your Identity (aka user) that has to implements the funtion `findIdentityByAccessToken`

see 
    \yii\web\IdentityInterface

to try your API on command line you can use cUrl as follows ( the token: XXXXXXXX_accessTokenString_XXXXXX )

note, the ":" divides user from password in the basic autentication, **the token is used as user**

**POST a JSON to MessageController (the pluralization is not an error)**

```
curl --user "XXXXXXXX_accessTokenString_XXXXXX:" -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST "http://rest.my-domain.com/messages" -d '{"email": "me@example.com"}'
```

**POST a JSON to UserController enabling xdebug**

```
curl  --user "XXXXXXXX_accessTokenString_XXXXXX:" --cookie 'XDEBUG_SESSION=1221221' -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST "http://rest.my-domain.com/messages" -d '{"email": "me@example.com"}'
```

**GET a JSON to UserController enabling xdebug**

```
curl --user "XXXXXXXX_accessTokenString_XXXXXX:" -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XGET "http://rest.my-domain.com/messages/123"
```

see also the Yii2 guide to REST services
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html